# Java, Statements, object creation is declaration statement or expression statement?

Tags: java, statements

```java
Bicycles myBike = new Bicycles();
```

hi, everyone, object creation statement is a declaration statement or expression statement. In oracle sit, I found that it is an expression statement. But I think it is more reasonable if it declaration statement. Your answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know what kind of expression/statement `new Bicycles();` is or what expression/statement `Bicycles myBike = new Bicycles();` is? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

This is both. A variable is declared, and then it is initialised with the value of an expression.

This is identical to:

```
Bicycles myBikes; // declaration
myBikes = new Bicycles(); // expression
```

Comment: I read that expression statements are not class level? They cannot appear at class level?

Comment: What's the source of that, and what is your definition of 'class level'?

Comment: I learned that there are 3 types of statements. 1. Declaration Statemerts 2. Expression Statements 3. Control flow Statements.  And Expression Statements and Control flow statements cannot appear at class level. for example I can't do                                                class Bicycles{
    int num = 1;
    if (num > 0 ){
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}

Comment: @koye that’s oversimplification to the point of incorrectness. Yes, you cannot have arbitrarily expressions at class level but you _can_ assign a value, based off an arbitrarily complex expression that returns the correct type, to a class level field.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Bicycles myBike = new Bicycles();
```

is either a [Field Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) or a [Local Variable Declaration Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).

An example for an [Expression Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) would be

```
myBike = new Bicycles();
```

where `myBike` needs to be declared somewhere else.

None of these statements are necessarily tied to an object creation.

Object creation (or, as the exact term is: a [Class Instance Creation Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)) is not a `Field Declaration`, it is not a `Local Variable Declaration Statement` and it is not an `Expression Statement`.

A `Class Instance Creation Expression` is just an `Expression`, nothing more!

Note that a `Field Declaration` and a `Local Variable Declaration Statement` allow an expression to be used to initialize the field / local variable. An `Expression Statement` **requires** an expression.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of both, *an expression* statement as well as *a declaration* statement:

```
Bicycles myBike = new Bicycles();
```

Given below is [an excerpt from Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html):

> An expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and
> method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of
> the language, that evaluates to a single value.  You've already seen examples
> of expressions, illustrated in bold below:
>
> **`int cadence = 0;`**
>
> **`anArray[0] = 100;`**

In the same page, you will find

> In addition to expression statements, there are two other kinds of
> statements: declaration statements and control flow statements. A
> declaration statement declares a variable. You've seen many examples
> of declaration statements already:
>
> `// declaration statement`
>
> `double aValue = 8933.234;`

By now, you might have already guessed that the following is *a declaration* statement, and *not an expression* statement:

```
Bicycles myBike;
```

and the following  is *an expression* statement, and *not a declaration* statement:

```
myBike = new Bicycles();
```